# Sed replace specific substring

Tags: sed

I have a file that's generated as an output to an SQL query. I need to replace the nulls in the file with blanks, so something like
`sed -e"s/null//g"` would work.

However there's a valid string of the form 'null/' (with a trailing forward slash) and that should not be replaced. Is there a way to replace only 'null' values while leaving 'null/' intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed one-liner:

```
sed 's#null\([^/]\|$\)#\1#g' file
```

should work for your requirement.

It searches pattern: `null and followed by a non-slash char (or EOL)`,

replace with the `followed non-slash char`.

Thus, `null/` won't be touched.

Comment: What if `null` is as the end of a line?

Answer (score 0):

I think this command should be enough:

```
sed -e "s/null[^/]//g"
```

Comment: this will change `nullable` -> `ble`, but I think OP expects `able`

Comment: I don't think OP has a problem with  `null` when it is inside a word, but that can be easily fixed